# How to fix NoReverseMatch at /user_login when trying to log in from project folder? DJango

Tags: django

I have a project folder **mysite** and my app folder **passwordValidate**. When I move the path of user_login to *passwordValidate/urls.py*, the login works but  same is not working from *mysite/urls.py*.

The error message is **Reverse for 'user_login' not found. 'user_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

*mysite/urls.py*

```
from passwordValidate import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('passwordValidate/',include('passwordValidate.urls')),
    path('user_login',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
]
```

*passwordValidate/views.py*

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user) 
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        return render(request,'passwordValidate/login.html')
```

*passwordValidate/templates/passwordValidate/base.html*

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'user_login' %}">Log In</a>
</li>
```

**console**

```
[16/Jan/2019 10:00:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2555
Not Found: /media/profile_pics/IMG_20181030_161728.jpg
[16/Jan/2019 10:00:39] "GET /media/profile_pics/IMG_20181030_161728.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2670
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[16/Jan/2019 10:00:44] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2577
Internal Server Error: /user_login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Desktop\django_lectures\Learning Jango\Django\NEW\PASSWORD VALIDATION\mysite\passwordValidate\views.py", line 74, in user_login
    return render(request,'passwordValidate/login.html')
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 442, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Anshul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user_login' not found. 'user_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[16/Jan/2019 10:00:47] "GET /user_login HTTP/1.1" 500 148137
```

Comment: Show the code that *isn't* working, not the code that is. In particular, show the contents of passwordValidate.urls.

Comment: The code above is not working

Comment: That doesn't make sense. mysite.urls is your main project URLs? What is the value of settings.ROOT_URLCONF?

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

Comment: Can you post the whole error output from your console?